# Initializing Pthreads inside While loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

im starting to use pthreads cpp library to resolve some homeworks.

In one of those, i do have to create a thread for each file named from 1 to T (T is fixed with Define as a positive integer), and this thread must process some informations of this file.

Actually, my thinking is to put a while loop in Main, like this:

```
pthread_t threads[T];

void *imprime(void *arg) {

    int a=-1, b=-1;
    string* t = reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(arg); //Recovering str
    string name = *t;
    cout<<"\nName: "<<name<<endl;
    ifstream inFile(nome.c_str());
    while(inFile>>a) {
            inFile>>b;
            cout<<"a: "<<a<<"\nb: "<<b<<endl;
    }
}

int main() {

    int lim = 1;
    string nome;
    int a = 0, b = 0;

    while(lim <= T) {
        nome = to_string(lim);
        cout<<"Opening: "<<lim<<endl;
        pthread_create(&threads[lim], NULL, &imprime, (void *)&nome);

        lim++;
    }
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

At first, the thread didnt run, nothing happened. So, i put the "cin.get()" under the while and it suddently works (What i didnt understood yet).

**But now, if T is 1 it works properly, but if T > 1, it doesnt work like it supposed to work.**

I put two files(names 1, 2 and 3; with ints 'a' and 'b' separated by an space):

```
/* 
   File '1' = "1 2"
   File '2' = "3 4"
   File '3' = "5 6"
*/
```

***and thats the output:***

```
Opening: 1
Opening: 2
Opening: 3

Nome: 3
a: 5
b: 6

Nome: 3
a: 5
b: 6

Nome: 3
a: 5
b: 6
```

By some reason, the program runs the entire while T times before starting the threads, and it overwrite every thread with the last one.

What can i do?

Comment: You miss to join all your threads before `main()` exits.

Comment: That's a very risky way of sharing data using a variable that gets recycled in `main`. Ideally you give the thread data which it assumes ownership of, you `main` never touches it again. There's no guarantee the thread will spin up and copy that string before the next loop iteration.

Comment: Why not use `std::thread` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Passing a pointer to `nome` is a bad idea as you can't be sure the individual thread copies the value before you change it again in `main`.

Make an array for the argument to the threads:

```
string threads_args[T];
```

and then do

```
    threads_args[lim] = to_string(lim);
    cout<<"Opening: "<<lim<<endl;
    pthread_create(&threads[lim], NULL, &imprime, (void *)&threads_args[lim]);
```

Further notice:

1) You should `join` the threads in main instead of using `cin.get`

2) `while(lim <= T)` shall be `while(lim < T)`. Currently you access outside array boundary. Also you probably want `lim` to start from `0` instead of `1` and then have `threads_args[lim] = to_string(lim+1);`

3) C++11 has std::thread which seems a better choice than pthread

Comment: Thank you, i did it and now it seems to work. About the std::threads, my teacher only gave us permission to use pthreads =/;

Comment: Great that it helped. Regarding your teacher: I think that is kind of strange - at least if you haven't already learned about std::thread. The thread system included in c++ should be the starting point, IMO.